# Windows Puppet Agent does not connect to Puppet Enterprise Master

Tags: azure, puppet

I have just created puppet labs enterprise master on a Windows azure vm using the default options. I am successfully able to access the PE console https://puppetmasterazure.cloudapp.net/. Being able to access the console, I think the master is configured correctly.

I have now created a new Windows VM in Azure and linked it to Puppet Master. However, the agent has failed to connect to the master (I also can't see the request for signing the new agent cert in the Puppet console). I can see the following error message in the windows event log.

```
    Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: No such host is known. 
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:69:in `timeout'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/sys/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1027:in `get'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/network/http/connection.rb:133:in `execute_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/network/http/connection.rb:80:in `block in request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/network/http/connection.rb:79:in `times'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/network/http/connection.rb:79:in `request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/network/http/connection.rb:58:in `get'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:84:in `http_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:63:in `http_get'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:97:in `block in find'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:178:in `block in do_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/request.rb:261:in `do_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:178:in `do_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:91:in `find'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/certificate/rest.rb:12:in `find'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:201:in `find'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/ssl/host.rb:201:in `certificate'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/ssl/host.rb:36:in `localhost'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/ssl/validator/default_validator.rb:26:in `initialize'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/ssl/validator.rb:27:in `new'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/ssl/validator.rb:27:in `default_validator'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/network/http_pool.rb:27:in `http_instance'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:58:in `network'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:83:in `http_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:63:in `http_get'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:97:in `block in find'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:178:in `block in do_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/request.rb:261:in `do_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:178:in `do_request'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/rest.rb:91:in `find'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/certificate/rest.rb:12:in `find'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:201:in `find'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/ssl/host.rb:201:in `certificate'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/ssl/host.rb:324:in `wait_for_cert'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/application/agent.rb:477:in `wait_for_certificates'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/application/agent.rb:318:in `run_command'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/application.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/application.rb:470:in `plugin_hook'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/application.rb:364:in `block in run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/util.rb:478:in `exit_on_fail'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/application.rb:364:in `run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/util/command_line.rb:137:in `run'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/lib/puppet/util/command_line.rb:91:in `execute'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Puppet Labs/Puppet Enterprise/puppet/bin/puppet:4:in `<main>'
```

Things I have validated,

- I have looked at the puppet.conf file and can confirm that the server name is correctly set to master.
- I am able to browse to the puppet console from the agent in internet explorer.

Any ideas how can I get the agent to communicate with the master?

Answer (score 1):

I had to make 2 changes which resulted in the certificate signing request being made from the agent to the master.

1. Open up cmd and telnet 
   "telnet puppetmaster.xxx.net 8140"
   This tells me that communication through to the master from the puppet is failing. D'oh should have remembered to open the port (endpoint) when configuring the agent. Open up the firewall ports, puppet uses 8140 as the default.
2. Locate the Puppet.conf file, on a windows box it is C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\etc. Validate the format of the server name, I previously had it configured as https://puppetmaster.xxx.net it should actually be without https.

> [main] server=puppetmasterazure.xxx.net pluginsync=true autoflush=true
>   archive_files=true archive_file_server=puppetmasterazure.xxx.net
>   graph=true environment=production

Voila! After making these changes, restart the service. This will force a connection attempt to the master. You should be able to see the certificate sign request in the Puppet enterprise console.